# Custom intervals in x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to add a custom interval to the x-axis. In the image below, this is what I'd like to achieve (from Excel).

[image].

Latex is putting its own interval as seen below:

[image]

My graph is defined as follows (I'm leaving out the co-ordinates and labels):

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel near ticks,
scale only axis,
x dir=reverse,
width=12cm]
\addplot [mark=none] coordinates {
};
\end{figure}
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to actually provide those tick labels or are they the data points? In the latter it's Excel's terribleness at plotting things that makes this possible :)

Comment: Without more info, for example demo data and a response to percusse, we can't really help here.